# sass :first-child not working

Tags: css, sass, pseudo-element

I have not been using SASS for a very long time and wanted to know if there are some issues with pseudo-elements such as `:first-child` or `:last-child` ?

Comment: In **scss** I had to do: `div { > div:nth-child(1) { styles } }`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

While @Andre is correct that there are issues with pseudo elements and their support, especially in older (IE) browsers, that support is improving all the time.

As for your question of, are there any issues, I'd say I've not really seen any, although the syntax for the pseudo-element can be a bit tricky, especially when first sussing it out. So:

```
div#top-level
  declarations: ...
  div.inside
    declarations: ...
    &:first-child
      declarations: ...
```

which compiles as one would expect:

```
div#top-level{
  declarations... }
div#top-level div.inside {
  declarations... }
div#top-level div.inside:first-child {
  declarations... }
```

I haven't seen any documentation on any of this, save for the statement that "sass can do everything that css can do." As always, with Haml and SASS the indentation is everything.

Comment: Very helpful - as above, don't forget to put **&** in front of **:first-child** as in **&:first-child**

Comment: In your example, shouldn't you expect this to compile to div#top-level:first-child?  The &:first-child is outside of the div.inside block, why would it be applied to div.inside?

Comment: @Danny: Absolutely correct -- I've updated the example to reflect.

Answer (score 23):

I think that it is better (for my expirience) to use: `:first-of-type`, `:nth-of-type()`, `:last-of-type`. It can be done whit a little changing of rules, but I was able to do much more than whit `*-of-type`, than `*-child` selectors.

Answer (score 12):

This is how I usually write pseudo-elements `:first-child`, `:last-child` and `:nth-child(n)` in **sass**

```
.my-class {
    &:first-child {
       // your css code             
    }

    &:last-child {
       // your css code             
    }

    &:nth-child(2) {
       // your css code             
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are still browsers out there that don't support those pseudo-elements (ie. :first-child, :last-child), so you have to 'deal' with this issue.

There is a good example how to make that work without using pseudo-elements:

> http://www.darowski.com/tracesofinspiration/2010/01/11/this-newbies-first-impressions-of-haml-and-sass/
>
> -- see the divider pipe example.

I hope that was useful.

Comment: On a side note, it's good to know that :first-child is with us since CSS2 and therefore is widely supported, whereas :last-child has been added only in CSS3.

Comment: I agree with you @Ronny, but still, people have to face some issues with older versions of browsers
Although :first_child appeared in CSS2, older browsers act buggy.
Reference: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstchild

Comment: Yeah, but when working on the most common cases - Removing the first/last border and the like, there's no reason to use the even-less-supported selector. Other than that, I'm all for aggressive degradation ;-)